# Partitioning a space such that a set of ergodic measures is uniquely supported on one of the sets

Tags: measure-theory, ergodic-theory

I'm reading a book on Ergodic theory, and it says that given a set X with a sigma algebra A, and a measurable automorphism T, then you can take a set of ergodic measures $\mu_i$ $\epsilon$ M$_T(X)$ $i=1,...,n$ (where M$_T(X)$ is the set of T-invariant probability measures) $\mu_i \ll \mu_j$ i $\ne$ j, and define disjoint sets A$_i$ such that $\cup_{i=1}^n A_i$ = X and $\mu_j$($A_i$) = $\delta_{ij}$.

I guess I don't understand how you can partition the space such that each measure is independently supported on their respective $A_i$. While still having the same measure as the entire space.

Comment: I am afraid that your statement may not be correct. Any two distinct ergodic measures are singular, they can not be absolutely continuous with respect to another. By the way there may be infinitely many ergodic measures and so I think we may not have such decomposition in this case. If you don't mind, would you please tell which it is from, maybe I can take a look to understand what the statement really means?

Comment: Ma$\widetilde{n}$e, "Ergodic Theory and Differentiable Dynamics, II.2 Example exercise 1. The book is translated from Portuguese and I've found other errors so it's possible that it's wrong (or of course, that I've misquoted it!).